# Having problem in making a responsive video carousal in react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Iam trying to make the carousel responsive but failing to do so. I have created 3 different item lists for different devices (mobile , tablet and desktop) but the videos does not switch properly the poster of the images work some how but then videos does not

React Code

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import AliceCarousel from 'react-alice-carousel';
import 'react-alice-carousel/lib/scss/alice-carousel.scss';
import { MdArrowBack, MdArrowForward } from 'react-icons/md';

import './carousel.css';

function VideoCarousel() {
  const items = {
    mobile: [
      {
        key: '1',
        videoSrc: './src/assets/carousel_data/mobile/Carousel01_mobile.mp4',
        poster: './src/assets/carousel_data/mobile/Carousel01Poster_mobile.png',
      },
      {
        key: '2',
        videoSrc: './src/assets/carousel_data/mobile/Carousel02_mobile.mp4',
        poster: './src/assets/carousel_data/mobile/Carousel02Poster_mobile.png',
      },
      {
        key: '3',
        videoSrc: './src/assets/carousel_data/mobile/Carousel03_mobile.mp4',
        poster: './src/assets/carousel_data/mobile/Carousel03Poster_mobile.png',
      },{
        key: '4',
        videoSrc: './src/assets/carousel_data/mobile/Carousel04_mobile.mp4',
        poster: './src/assets/carousel_data/mobile/Carousel04Poster_mobile.png',
      },
    ],
    tablet: [
      {
        key: '1',
        videoSrc: './src/assets/carousel_data/tablet/Carousel01_tablet.mp4',
        poster: './src/assets/carousel_data/tablet/Carousel01Poster_tablet.png',
      },
      {
        key: '2',
        videoSrc: './src/assets/carousel_data/tablet/Carousel02_tablet.mp4',
        poster: './src/assets/carousel_data/tablet/Carousel02Poster_tablet.png',
      },
      {
        key: '3',
        videoSrc: './src/assets/carousel_data/tablet/Carousel03_tablet.mp4',
        poster: './src/assets/carousel_data/tablet/Carousel03Poster_tablet.png',
      },{
        key: '4',
        videoSrc: './src/assets/carousel_data/tablet/Carousel04_tablet.mp4',
        poster: './src/assets/carousel_data/tablet/Carousel04Poster_tablet.png',
      },
    ],
    desktop: [
      {
        key: '1',
        videoSrc: './src/assets/carousel_data/desktop/Carousel01_desktop.mp4',
        poster: './src/assets/carousel_data/desktop/Carousel01Poster_desktop.png',
      },
      {
        key: '2',
        videoSrc: './src/assets/carousel_data/desktop/Carousel02_desktop.mp4',
        poster: './src/assets/carousel_data/desktop/Carousel02Poster_desktop.png',
      },
      {
        key: '3',
        videoSrc: './src/assets/carousel_data/desktop/Carousel03_desktop.mp4',
        poster: './src/assets/carousel_data/desktop/Carousel03Poster_desktop.png',
      },
      {
        key: '4',
        videoSrc: './src/assets/carousel_data/desktop/Carousel04_desktop.mp4',
        poster: './src/assets/carousel_data/desktop/Carousel04Poster_desktop.png',
      },
    ],
  };

  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState(items.desktop);

  const responsive = {
    0: { items: 1, key: 'mobile' },
    768: { items: 1, key: 'tablet' },
    1024: { items: 1, key: 'desktop' },
  };

  const carouselRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      const width = window.innerWidth;

      if (width <= 480) {
        setSelectedItems(items.mobile);
      } else if (width > 480 && width <= 768) {
        setSelectedItems(items.tablet);
      } else {
        setSelectedItems(items.desktop);
      }
    };

    // Set initial items based on the current window width
    handleResize();

    // Listen for window resize events
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    // Cleanup event listener on component unmount
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, [items.mobile, items.tablet, items.desktop]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Set up a custom timer to change slides
    const autoplayInterval = 8000; // Adjust as needed

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      carouselRef.current.slideNext(); // Move to the next slide
    }, autoplayInterval);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="video-carousel-container">
      <AliceCarousel
        items={selectedItems.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.key} className="video-slide">
            <div className="video-container">
              <video controls muted poster={item.poster}>
                <source src={item.videoSrc} type="video/mp4" />
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
        responsive={responsive}
        buttonsDisabled
        ref={carouselRef}
        renderPrevButton={() => <MdArrowBack />}
        renderNextButton={() => <MdArrowForward />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default VideoCarousel;
```

I have been using media queries also in the Css

Css file-

```
/* Default styles for all resolutions */
.video-carousel-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-slide {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.video-slide video {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.alice-carousel__prev-btn,
.alice-carousel__next-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.material-icons {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.alice-carousel__prev-btn {
  left: 15px;
}

.alice-carousel__next-btn {
  right: 15px;
}

.video-slide video::poster {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/* Media queries for different resolutions */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .video-carousel-container {
    height: 1024px; /* Set the height for mobile */
  }

  .alice-carousel__prev-btn,
  .alice-carousel__next-btn {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .video-carousel-container {
    height: 768px; /* Set the height for tablet */
  }

  .alice-carousel__prev-btn,
  .alice-carousel__next-btn {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .video-carousel-container {
    height: 600px; /* Set the height for desktop */
  }

  .alice-carousel__prev-btn,
  .alice-carousel__next-btn {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
  }
}
```

I tried using media queries but different videos and posters are not working together. Current Output
[image: Desktop View]
[image: Tablet view]
[image: Mobile view] The buttons added for controls are also not working consistently sometimes missing sometimes does not work`[Video of the output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D6pgO131tJw4SNd6rgfLf2isFcOihXeb/view?usp=sharing)